# Add column in html table if new variable in (database) table column

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table named 'traffic' and two columns 'line' (there are over 50 lines) and 'vehicle' (over 300). This table contains a list of all of the lines and the vehicle they depend on. Each line has several vehicles and I need to group them (vehicles) in columns by line.

```
line     | vehicle
______________________
line_a   | veh1
line_a   | veh12
line_a   | veh123
line_b   | veh14
line_b   | veh15
line_b   | veh16
line_c   | veh17
line_c   | veh18
```

Expected Output

```
line_a   |    line_b   |    line_c   | .... to line 50
______________________________________
veh1          veh14         veh17
veh12         veh15         veh18
veh123        veh16
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: I would prefer php to do the job.

Comment: First step would be for you to access all the tables within the database. When all tables have been fetched loop through the array of tables and for each table build a new HTML table with the desired output. ! good luck, if you have code and you are stuck let us know

Answer (score 0):

- load all to php arrays
- iterate once and collect unique lines via $helparr[$line]=array(), but also collect values per line array_push($helparr[$line],$vehicle)
- iterate again: for all $helparr (output $line, for all $helparr[$line] (output $vehicle))

...guess, half of your coding work is done now...

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to fetch all the records from your database,
here i'm using a demo array `$input` just for example, you do not need this array when you are fetching from database, you can start from `foreach`

```
<?php 
$input = array(0=>array('line'=>'line_a','vehicle'=>'veh1'),
               1=>array('line'=>'line_b','vehicle'=>'veh2'),
               2=>array('line'=>'line_c','vehicle'=>'veh6'),
               3=>array('line'=>'line_a','vehicle'=>'veh5'),
               4=>array('line'=>'line_c','vehicle'=>'veh9')
         );

$newArr =array();
foreach($input as $key =>$val)
{
    $newArr[$val['line']][] = $val['vehicle'];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArr);

?>
```

your `$newArr` looks like this

```
Array
(
    [line_a] => Array
        (
            [0] => veh1
            [1] => veh5
        )

    [line_b] => Array
        (
            [0] => veh2
        )

    [line_c] => Array
        (
            [0] => veh6
            [1] => veh9
        )

)
```

your vehicles are sorted according to their respective lines and you can use `$newArray` to print according to your need.
I hope this will work for you!